# Installing SSH private key on FreeNAS for outgoing SSH/rsync

Tags: ssh, freenas, ssh-agent, rsa

I am attempting to establish an outgoing SSH session from my FreeNAS to my web server. My hosting service requires RSA keys for SSH access.

I have generated keys with `ssh-keygen -t rsa`, and have loaded the public key to my hosting service cPanel.

With `ssh-agent`, I get:

```
setenv SSH_AUTH_SOCK /tmp/ssh-ctFGdCRTcscD/agent.18840;
setenv SSH_AGENT_PID 18841;
echo Agent pid 18841;
```

Then when I use `ssh-add /{path to key}` I still get the error `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.`

If I attempt an SSH connection, I get `Permission denied (publickey).`

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you also authorize the key within cPanel?

Comment: I don't see any function to authorize the key. It listed under "Manage current keys", with options to "Remove Key" or add IP. I do not have an IP specified since I have a dynamic IP.

Comment: Under "Manage SSH keys" I see a list of keys, and in the "Authorization status" column I see "authorized", which I can change by clicking on the "manage" link to the far right.

Comment: Huh, I don't have an "Authorization Status" column. Must be an option for the host or different cPanel version. In any case, @Jakuje's answer fixed it on my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By running `ssh-agent`, you start it, but do not set up the connection to it properly. The problem is that child process can not modify the environment of the parent process. The intended way of starting `ssh-agent` is

```
eval `ssh-agent`
```

or (to start a new shell with the environment):

```
ssh-agent /bin/bash
```

in that case, you will get the environment set up properly and should be able to add your keys to your `ssh-agent`.